# MVC 3 DataAnnotation with Linq2Sql generated class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I have created my ORM model using Linq to SQL. By using the code

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle) %>
```

I'm trying to display my own string, instead of `NewsTitle`.

To do so, I tried the following scenario:

Let's say that I have the `News` class (generated by the Ling To Sql)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.News")]
public partial class News : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  [..]
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_NewsTitle", DbType="NVarChar(200) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string NewsTitle
    { 
      get { [...] }
      set { [...] }
    }
}
```

Then, I've created that class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(News_Meta))]
public partial class News
{
}

public class News_Meta
{
    [Required]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "MyOwnString")]
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the `NewsTitle` label is generated instead of `MyOwnString`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First of all, you're not telling what the problem is. It's very hard to help you if you don't provide that information. Beside that, I can suggest you, if this is a new development, to use something more appropriate than linq2sql which is legacy and no longer developed. Moving to EF 4.2 and POCO classes will give you a better and easier model to work with.

Comment: Please read the last line of my description. That scenatio is a part of the project that I'm working on, I can't change the model on that developing stage

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following code in view if you just want to display another name

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle, new { @value = "String"}) %>
```